# VBA code (Set range, define value, and put a color)

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

Basically this is the code I have right now. I want to create a module, that in any worksheet, I set the range, then I define certain values (Example: between 0,15 and 0,28) and will finally put a color on the cells with that numbers. But I'm gettting some errors, and I'm having a hard time with the last if.

```
Sub ColorFrames()

Dim range1 As Range
Dim range2 As Range
Dim valor1 As Variant
Dim valor2 As Variant
Dim Sh As Worksheet

' CODE

Set range1 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Range with data to be validated", Title:="Range", Type:=8)

valor1 = InputBox("Values between:")
valor2 = InputBox("and:")

If valor1 = "" And valor2 = "" Then
 ' and if < 0 and > 1... How?
    MsgBox ("Insert Values between 0 and 1! Thank you")
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If Range(range1).Value >= valor1 And Range(range1).Value <= valor2 Then
        Sh.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Sh.Value = ""
    End If
Next Sh

Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: First, you need to explicitly define your `range1` size. If you allow multilple selections, then you have to iterate through it in your code per sheet. Like a `Nested For Each Loop`. Also this line: `Range(Range1).Value` doesn't quite fit with any `Range Object Syntax`. It should be something like `Range(range1.Address).Value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option that works on a user range (with the current selection as default) and than loops until a valid range and coundary conditions are supplied is below (for a range on a single sheet)

```
Sub ColorFrames()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim vArr
Dim dblV1 As Double
Dim dblV2 As Double
Dim bCondition As Boolean

Do
Set rng1 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Range with data to be validated", Title:="Range", Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
Loop While rng1 Is Nothing

Do
vArr = Application.InputBox("Please enter lower and upper bounds, separated by a "", """, Title:="Values", Default:="0,1", Type:=2)
valor1 = Split(vArr, ",")
dblV1 = CDbl(valor1(0))
dblV2 = CDbl(valor1(1))
bCondition = (dblV1 >= 0) And (dvlv2 <= 1) And (dblV2 > dblV1)
Loop While Not bCondition

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each rng2 In rng1
    If rng2.Value >= dblV1 And rng2.Value <= dblV2 Then
    With rng2
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        .Value = vbNullString
    End With
    End If
Next rng2
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```